# Joomla 3.2 component mailer

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, email

I have a component that I built to make calculations.  I would like to allow the person to email their results to themselves.   I have tried to create a mail function in the controller of the default.php for the tmpl page, shown here:

```
    public  function sendMail () {

    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

    $config = JFactory::getConfig();

    $sender = array(
        $config->get( 'config.mailfrom' ),
        $config->get( 'config.fromname' ) );
    $mailer->setSender($sender);

    $recipient = $calculatorEmailAddress;

    $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);


    $body = '<div id="emtresults">'
        . '<table border="0" width="75%" max-width="750px" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table">'
        . '<tr class="calcresultslabels">'
        . '  <th> </th>'
        . '    <th>10foot</th>'
        . '    <th>20foot</th>'
        . '   <th>Savings</th>'
        . '   </tr>'
        . ' <tr class="calcresults">'
        . '    <th>Materials</th>'
        . '   <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($tenmat1)?></td>'
        . ' <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($twentymat1)?></td>'
        . ' <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($matsavings1)?></td>'
        . ' </tr>'
        . ' <tr class="calcresults">'
        . '    <th>Tax</th>'
        . '    <td align="center"><div> $  <?php echo round($tentax1)?></td>'
        . '    <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($twentytax1)?></td>'
        . '   <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($taxsavings1)?></td>'
        . ' <tr>'
        . ' <tr class="calcresults">'
        . '    <th>Hours</th>'
        . '    <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($tenhours1)?></td>'
        . '    <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($twentyhours1)?></td>'
        . '     <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($hourssavings1)?></td>'
        . ' </tr>'
        . ' <tr class="calcresults">'
        . '   <th>Total</th>'
        . '   <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($tentotal1)?></td>'
        . '   <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($twentytotal1)?></td>'
        . '   <td align="center"> $  <?php echo round($totalsavings1)?></td>'
        . ' </tr>'
        . ' </table>'
        . ' </div>';

    $mailer->isHTML(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mailer->setSubject('EMT Calculator App Results');
    $mailer->setBody($body);

    $send = $mailer->Send();
    if ( $send !== true ) {
        echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString();
    } else {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    }

}
```

I then have the action in the /components/component/views/view/tmpl/default.php and code it as here:

```
<form method='post' action='/index.php?option=com_emtapp&view=calculators&task=sendMail'>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Email your Results:</td><td align="center"><div> <input type="email" name="calculatorEmailAddress" value=""/></div></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="tenmat1" value="<?php echo round($tenmat)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="twentymat1" value="<?php echo round($twentymat)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="matsavings1" value="<?php echo round($matsavings)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="tentax1" value="<?php echo round($matsavings)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="twentytax1" value="<?php echo round($twentytax)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="taxsavings1" value="<?php echo round($taxsavings)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="tenhours1" value="<?php echo round($tenhours)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="twentyhours1" value="<?php echo round($twentyhours)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hourssavings1" value="<?php echo round($hourssavings)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="tentotal1" value="<?php echo round($tentotal)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="twentytotal1" value="<?php echo round($twentytotal)?>">
<input type="hidden" name="totalsavings1" value="<?php echo round($totalsavings)?>">


<input type='submit' value='Email Your Results'/>
</form>
```

However it will not send any email. Does any one have any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can check if your joomla installation able to send other emails? (like registration confirmation etc)

Comment: Yes.  It is working.  I get them all the time.  Could it be that I have other submit actions on the same page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation issues and would be better off on [the Joomla Q&A StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I posted over on that site, however, the editor will not format the CODE properly.  I can only post one strip of code, for some reason on that site.